# Facebook, Sorry, this application is currently experiencing a prblm. Please try again later

Tags: facebook

I have created a facebook app that retrieves user_posts to determine which education program related to user interests. I was approved permissions via Direct Support and public flagged at App Review settings. My test users can access app but non-test users cannot access publicly.

The error like this.

Sorry, this application is currently experiencing a problem. Please try again later.

Comment: i don´t think anyone here can help you, stackoverflow is a platform for third party developers, there is no direct facebook support here. we can´t know what the issue is, especially if we can´t even test your app.

Comment: Hi @luschn, thank you for your reply but I have to find anyone who encountered this error on this situation before. I wrote there because of they advise stackoverflow for detailed tech questions at facebook developer group.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem via resubmission with add a new permission. When I added a new permission I did see App Verification didn't approve by Direct Support.